# Why use CoInitialize(0); in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have been writing a C++ program where I am creating a shortcut link for an exe file, and to do that I need to write the `CoInitialize(0);` at the starting. And without it the code does not work. Can someone help me to know why we use it?

I just want to know why we use this function.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize), 'Initializes the COM library on the current thread and identifies the concurrency model as single-thread apartment (STA).'. Basically it initialises some library that you are using (even if you didn't know it) that needs to be initialised otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Why use `CoInitialize()`? You shouldn't: new applications should use `CoInitializeEx()`.

Comment: Because the API that you are using to create the shortcut is COM based and COM has to be initialized. Basically, almost all modern apps will use COM at some point.

Comment: IShellLink is a COM interface, it requires that you are explicit about how you keep libraries thread-safe.  An important detail that often gets skipped in library design, but not in COM.  You make a *promise*, cross your heart hope to die, that (in this case) you'll start a message loop on the same thread.  Or never call into the library from a worker thread so thread-safety is not a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CoInitialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize), and the extended and more recommended version [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex), are used to initialize the [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) library for the current thread:

> Initializes the COM library on the current thread
> ...
> New applications should call CoInitializeEx instead of CoInitialize.

It has to be called for each thread that uses COM.

Note that `CoInitialize()` identifies the concurrency model as single-thread apartment (STA), whereas with `CoInitializeEx()` you have the freedom to specify the concurrency model.

More about COM threads and other related issues: [Processes, Threads, and Apartments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments).

In case you are not familiar with [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) (from the documentation):

> COM is a platform-independent, distributed, object-oriented system for creating binary software components that can interact. COM is the foundation technology for Microsoft's OLE (compound documents) and ActiveX (Internet-enabled components) technologies.

If your program requires calling one of the initialization functions above, it means that either you directly, or any library you use, are using COM.

Note that each successful call to `CoInitialize/Ex()` must be matched with a call to [`CoUninitialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize).

---

Edit:

As @IInspectable commented, using a COM object on a thread does not strictly require calling `CoInitialize/Ex()`.

But, since COM objects have threading requirements as noted above, calling it ensures that the current thread uses the proper COM concurrency model.
See [Why does CoCreateInstance work even though my thread never called CoInitialize? The curse of the implicit MTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613).

Comment: *"either you directly, or any library you use are using COM"* - That's not *actually* the reason. The reason is that COM objects have threading requirements, and `CoInitialize[Ex]` initializes the calling thread into one of the available threading apartments. [Processes, Threads, and Apartments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments) has more information.

Comment: @IInspectable what you wrote is correct of course, but still relevant only if the program actually uses any COM module. So I don't see how my statement about COM usage is wrong. The OP can look into the links I posted (or into your link which I added to my answer) to find out more about COM and what's actually going on when you call `CoInitialize[Ex]`. But first they have to be aware of it.

Comment: Your statement is wrong, because using a COM object on a thread does not strictly require calling `CoInitialize[Ex]` ([Why does CoCreateInstance work even though my thread never called CoInitialize? The curse of the implicit MTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613) explains this).

Comment: Besides, it's best not to call `CoUninitialize` at all. Just let the thread die and have the system clean up. Properly cleaning up after COM is near impossible (see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/1169#issuecomment-926877227) as an example).

Comment: Regarding `CoUninitialize` you raise an interesting point. BTW the documentation still insists _"A thread must call CoUninitialize once for each successful call it has made to the CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx"_.